# Problems with PyQt5

Tags: python, apt, qt

Quoting:

> I developed a similar application using PyQt4 and Qt4-designer. You
>   have to install pyqt4 all modules:
>
> sudo apt-get install qt4-default qt4-designer qt4-doc qt4-dev-tools
>   python-qt4
>
> So in your case just change all 4-5 i.e qt4 -- qt5.

Well, I tried that and got the following:

```
E: Unable to locate package qt5-designer 
E: Unable to locate package qt5-dev-tools 
E: Unable to locate package python-qt5
```

So I assume it would be safer to proceed with pyqt 4 rather than pyqt5?

Comment: I've edited your question so it looks a bit nicer and is easier to read. I wouldn't get upset about people editing your question its fairly common on the site, and it might mean someone is more likely to answer it. I suggest taking the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how things work around here, we are not very similar to other forums.